# python BeautifulSoup get all href in Children of div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and I've been trying to get links and inner text from this html code :

```
<div class="someclass">
  <ul class="listing">
        <li>
          <a href="http://link1.com" title="">title1</a>
                </li>
        <li>
           <a href="http://link2.com" title="">title2</a>
                 </li>
        <li>
           <a href="http://link3.com" title="">title3</a>
                 </li>
        <li>
           <a href="http://link4.com" title="">title4</a>
                  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want **only and all** links from href `http://link.com` and the inner text `title`

i tried this code

```
    div = soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'listing'})
for li in div:
    all_li = li.find_all('li')
    for link in all_li.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

but no luck can someone help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) which returns a list in your second *forloop* where you should use [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

```
>>> for ul in soup.find_all('ul', class_='listing'):
...     for li in ul.find_all('li'):
...         a = li.find('a')
...         print(a['href'], a.get_text())
... 
http://link1.com title1
http://link2.com title2
http://link3.com title3
http://link4.com title4
```

You can also use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of nested *forloop*

```
>>> for a in soup.select('.listing li a'):
...     print(a['href'], a.get_text(strip=True))
... 
http://link1.com title1
http://link2.com title2
http://link3.com title3
http://link4.com title4
```

Answer (score 3):

Get all the a tags once you select the ul then extract the text from the a's with the title attributes and the hrefs.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="someclass">
  <ul class="listing">
        <li>
          <a href="http://link1.com" title="">title1</a>
                </li>
        <li>
           <a href="http://link2.com" title="">title2</a>
                 </li>
        <li>
           <a href="http://link3.com" title="">title3</a>
                 </li>
        <li>
           <a href="http://link4.com" title="">title4</a>
                  </li>
  </ul>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
ul = soup.select("ul.listing")[0]
links = [a["href"] for a in ul.select("a[href]")]
text = [a.text for a in ul.select("a[title]")]
```

Which will give you:

```
['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4']
['http://link1.com', 'http://link2.com', 'http://link3.com', 'http://link4.com']
```

If you actually  have multiple ul's that match the class:

```
uls = soup.select("ul.listing")
links = [a["href"] for ul in uls for a in ul.select("a[href]") ]
text = [a.text for ul in uls for a in  ul.select("a[title]")]

print(text)
print(links)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `all_li` is actually a *list* of `li` elements. In the next line you try to use it as if it was a single element instead:

```
all_li.find_all('a')
```

Instead you will need to iterate through elements of `all_li` and call `find_all` on *each* of them.

Something like this should work:

```
uls = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'listing'})
for ul in uls:
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        for link in li.find_all('a'):
            url = link.get('href')
            contents = link.text
            print (url, contents)
```

This will yield

```
('http://link1.com', 'title1')
('http://link2.com', 'title2')
('http://link3.com', 'title3')
('http://link4.com', 'title4')
```