# using BeautifulSoup to find the href link

Tags: python, html, href

i am using BeautifulSoup to find the href by class "reply_to".

```
<div class="message">
   <div class="reply_to details">
        In reply to <a href="#go_to_message18" onclick="return 
        GoToMessage(18)">this message</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

now the code below can find the reply_to element, but then how to go down to  and retrieve href from

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed.input[0], "html.parser")
alldefaultmesssages = soup.select(".message.default")
alldefaultmesssages.select_one(".reply_to")
```

Comment: What do you want? The contents of the `href` attribute, the text, or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python BeautifulSoup get all href in Children of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107353/python-beautifulsoup-get-all-href-in-children-of-div) ... or [Beautiful Soup find href inside a child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328617/beautiful-soup-find-href-inside-a-child-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get to the child `anchor` tag of the `reply_to` element:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<div class="message">
   <div class="reply_to details">
        In reply to <a href="#go_to_message18" onclick="return
        GoToMessage(18)">this message</a>
   </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find("div", class_="reply_to").a.get('href'))
#>>> #go_to_message18
```